# Telling a enum what sub class type to use

Tags: java, enums, constructor

Hello to explain what i am trying to do its best i show you

public class Main {

```
public enum Types{
    ONE(One.class),TWO(Two.class),THREE(Three.class);

    Class<?> type;

    private Types(Class<?> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}

public class Manager {
    ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void Load() {
        //THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
        //I know it can be done like this below to add them in to the array with the types
        numbers.add((One) new Number());
        numbers.add((Two) new Number());
        numbers.add((One) new Number());
        numbers.add((Three) new Number());

        //But i want to be able to add them like this.
        numbers.add(Types.ONE.type.newInstance());

    }

    public void Run() {

        if (numbers.isEmpty()) {
            Load();
        }

        for (Number n : numbers) {
            n.call();
        }
    }
}

public class Number {
    public void call() {

    }       
}

public class One extends Number {   
    @Override
    public void call() {
    }
}

public class Two extends Number {   
    @Override
    public void call() {
    }
}

public class Three extends Number { 
    @Override
    public void call() {
    }
}
```

}

If you look for the comments in the code i am trying to add the "Number" to the array but with is sub class.

**Now this is a example in the application i want it for the objects have parameters in the constructors. Can any one point me in the right direction.**

The reason i just do not add them by using .add is in the real application there are 100s of objection to add to the array list and when i get these object there stored with there enum to show what type they are. Also these objects get changed regularly.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the variable `type` in `Types` is of type `Class<?>`.  This `Class` object could represent *any* class object, which is not necessarily in the `Number` class hierarchy you've created.

Any object returned by `newInstance` could be of any type, so it can't be allowed by the compiler to be sent to an `ArrayList<Number>` as a parameter; it might not match.

Add an upper bound to the type of `type`:

```
enum Types{
    ONE(One.class),TWO(Two.class),THREE(Three.class);

    // add ? extends Number here
    Class<? extends Number> type;  

    // add ? extends Number here
    private Types(Class<? extends Number> type) {  
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

You'll still have to catch all of the reflection-related exceptions: `IllegalAccessException` and `InstantiationException`.

Also note that in Java 9+, [`Class.newInstance` is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--); you should replace that call with

```
getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

which also throws `NoSuchMethodException` and `InvocationTargetException`.

Comment: Yes i realised this and added.  Class<? extends Minion> object; But the problem i am having is that my "Minion" objects constructor is public Minion(ArmorStand armorStand, MinionDataCore dataCore, Player PlayerWhoLoaded) { and when i read up on the .newInstance() it says is only calls the constructor with not parametors

Comment: Also, to save some typing, perhaps add `Number create() { return type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance() }` method to the `Types` enum.

Comment: Uh, `Minion`?  If you have a different constructor to call, you'll have to pass in  the proper `Class` objects representing the types of the constructor parameters to `getDeclaredConstructor`.